# RegExp match until end of word

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to write a JavaScript variable-highlighting regular expression, so that variable declaration names are highlighted by the following code:

```
var foo = 'bar',
    raz = 'zar',
    wat
```

So far I have a regexp that whichights `foo` and `raz` but not `wat` since the regexp works by ending with the `=` character.

```
(var|,)(.*?)=
```

How can I modify this regexp so that is also highlights `wat`?

I have a feeling that the missing piece is to swap the `=` with an ending word boundary match.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time using regex to match keywords like that, you should use regex as part of EBNF or similar.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript regex to do this matching?  I can't see how that would work, since there is no regex option where `.` will match the newlines in JS.

Comment: @F.J OP could replace it with `[\s\S]`.

Comment: @alex OP also says the current regex highlights `foo` and `raz`, so it sounds like he isn't using JavaScript.  I just want to confirm that.

Comment: I didn't realise he wasn't parsing with JS too. :)

Comment: OP, what's the significance of `xml` tag?

Comment: @alex Well he could be parsing with JS, but if he is he definitely didn't test the current regex on his sample string.

Comment: @alex I'm in XML regex, and my original regexp matches the variables as does anubhava's solution.

Comment: @BartKiers The `"var novar"` problem is null in my case since I'm matching variables before I match strings and the string overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this regex:

```
(?:var|,)\s*(\w+)(?= *=|$)
```

#### Live Demo: http://rubular.com/r/WEfFpAtWJ2

Comment: @BartKiers what's the general case? It seems to work.

Comment: @anubhava can you explain how the last segment works?

Comment: @JacksonGariety: Last segment is `(?:=|$)` which matches literal `=` or end of input anchor `$`. `?:` is used for non-capturing group. You can use `(=|$)` also.

Comment: @BartKiers that's where order of operations comes in. Strings and comments are the last things i'll match, so it won't be an issue.

Comment: This actually highlights keys of objects also, which I don't really want. Any way to make sure a `var` is at the beginning, even if on a different line?

Comment: This one seems to highlight almost the entire document, unfortunately. And XML regex doesn't have the `/m` support.

Comment: It makes sense that it would highlight anything since it's matchinv the word var or every beginning character.

Comment: I also think it has to be done in two different regexps, which is fine. One should match the variables after var, and the others after the commas.

Comment: Can there be newline character also in this variable declaration?

Comment: anubhava. Yes, and I tihnk I almost have it. Check this out: `var(.*?)(?:$|=).*(?:, )(.*?)(?:$|=)` that one matches everything. Now I need to get it to work without `/m`

Comment: Instead of `$` you can use `\z` and avoid `/m`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42073/discussion-between-jackson-gariety-and-anubhava)

Comment: For this to be truly correct it needs the negative lookahead you send me in chat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
(var)((.*)=(.*),?)+
```

Comment: line starts with var, followed by more than one key=value pair with optinal , at then end. we can make it more stricter if you want.

Comment: This actually highlights keys of objects also, similar to the answer above. Any way to make sure a `var` is at the beginning, even if on a different line?

Comment: You can add ^ at the beginning and $ at the end.

Comment: `^(var)((.*)=(.*),?)+$` doesn't seem to make any difference.